# How to mitigate "Access to modified closure" in cases where the delegate is called directly

Tags: c#, closures, resharper

My understanding is that the "Access to modified closure" warning is there to warn me about accessing local variables from a delegate when the delegate might be stored and called later or called on a different thread so that the local variable isn't actually available at the time of actual code execution. This is sensible of course.

But what if I am creating a delegate that I know is going to be called immediately in the same thread? The warning then is not needed. For example the warning is generated in the code:

```
delegate void Consume();

private void ConsumeConsume(Consume c)
{
    c();
}

public int Hello()
{
    int a = 0;

    ConsumeConsume(() => { a += 9; });

    a = 1;

    return a;
}
```

There can be no problem here since `ConsumeConsume` always calls the function immediately. Is there any way around this? Is there some way to annotate the function `ConsumeConsume` to indicate the ReSharper that the delegate will be called immediately?

Interestingly, when I replace the `ConsumeConsume(() => { a += 9; });` line with:

```
new List<int>(new[] {1}).ForEach(i => { a += 9; });
```

which does the same thing, no warning is generated. Is this just an in-built exception for ReSharper or is there something I can do similarly to indicate that the delegate is called immediately?

I am aware that I can disable these warnings but that is not a desired outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `JetBrains.Annotations` package with NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations

Mark the passed in delegate with the `InstantHandle` attribute.

```
private void ConsumeConsume([InstantHandle] Consume c)
{
    c();
}
```

From `InstantHandle`'s description:

> Tells code analysis engine if the parameter is completely handled when the invoked method is on stack. If the parameter is a delegate, indicates that delegate is executed while the method is executed. If the parameter is an enumerable, indicates that it is enumerated while the method is executed.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html

If you don't want to add the whole package to your project, it's enough to just add the attribute yourself, although it's hacky in my opinion.

```
namespace JetBrains.Annotations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    public class InstantHandleAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.